# Why is this javascript code not working on Android browser or in IE?

Tags: javascript, android, internet-explorer

In Chrome, this works just fine, but I am having problems when viewing the page in the default browser on an Android tablet and in IE. It seems the problem lies somewhere with setting the innerHTML.

Here is the code

```
function common_get_order_xml()
{
  //console.log(common_get_common_order_xml());
  var parser = new DOMParser(); //create a new DOMParser
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(common_get_common_order_xml(), "application/xml"); //convert the string to xml

  doc.getElementsByTagName('Mats')[0].innerHTML = mattes_get_mattes_xml().replace("<Mats>", "").replace("</Mats>", "").replace(/<fillet><\/fillet>/g, "").replace(/<fillet\/>/g, ""); //add the mattes, remove empty fillet tags
  doc.getElementsByTagName('Openings')[0].innerHTML = mattes_get_openings_xml().replace("<Openings>", "").replace("</Openings>", ""); //Add the openings
  if (typeof(moulding_get_moulding_xml()) != "undefined")
  {
    doc.getElementsByTagName('Moulding')[0].innerHTML = moulding_get_moulding_xml().replace("<Moulding>", "").replace("</Moulding>", ""); //Add the moulding
  }
  if (typeof(glazing_get_glass_xml()) != "undefined")
  {
    doc.getElementsByTagName('Glass')[0].innerHTML = glazing_get_glass_xml().replace("<Glass>", "").replace("</Glass>", ""); //Add the moulding
  }
  var serializer = new XMLSerializer(); //create a new XMLSerializer
  common_order_xml = serializer.serializeToString(doc); //convert the xml back to a string
  console.log(doc);
  alert(common_order_xml);

  common_set_sizes(doc);
  common_set_total(common_order_xml);


  return doc;
}
```

Comment: Which Android tablet - model and OS version.

Comment: It's a Double Power brand. The android version is 4.1.1. This is a link to it: http://www.walmart.com/ip/Double-Power-7-Tablet-8GB-Memory-Dual-Core-Bonus-Kit/29340913

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function common_get_order_xml()
{
  var mattes_xml = mattes_get_mattes_xml().multiReplace({"<fillet></fillet>" : "", "<fillet/>" : ""}); //remove empty fillet tags
  common_order_xml = common_order_xml.replace("<Mats></Mats>", mattes_xml);

  common_order_xml = common_order_xml.replace("<Openings></Openings>", mattes_get_openings_xml()); //Add the openings

  var moulding_xml = moulding_get_moulding_xml();
  if (typeof(moulding_xml) != "undefined")
  {
    common_order_xml = common_order_xml.replace("<Moulding></Moulding>", moulding_xml); //Add the openings
  }

  var glass_xml = glazing_get_glass_xml();
  if (typeof(glass_xml) != "undefined")
  {
    common_order_xml = common_order_xml.replace("<Glass></Glass>", glass_xml); //Add the openings
  }



  var parser = new DOMParser(); //create a new DOMParser
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(common_order_xml, "application/xml"); //convert the string to xml
  common_set_sizes(doc);
  common_set_total(common_order_xml);


  return doc;
}
```